# How can I find out, what causes this Bukkit Worldgenerator-Error?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm coding a Minecraft SkyGrid Generator in Java with Bukkit.
When im using cobblestone for every block, it works fine. But when i'm trying to get a random block, the generator runs into an error. Here's my code:

```
@Override
public ChunkData generateChunkData(World world, Random random, int ChunkX, int ChunkZ, BiomeGrid biome) {
    ChunkData data = createChunkData(world);

    Material material = Material.COBBLESTONE;

    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        for(int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < world.getMaxHeight() / 4; y++) {
                boolean foundBlock = false;

                while(!foundBlock) {
                    int i = random.nextInt(Material.values().length);
                    material = Material.values()[i];
                    if(material != null && !material.isLegacy() && material.isBlock() && material != Material.AIR) {
                        foundBlock = true;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(material);
                data.setBlock(x*4, y*4, z*4, material);
            }
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

As you see i'm printing the materials into the console. But this doesn't give me any informations because some blocks seems to cause the error but sometimes they works fine and another block seems to cause the error. Here is the console-printing:

```
[10:46:18] [Server thread/INFO]: Custom Map Seeds:  Village: 10387312 Desert: 14357617 Igloo: 14357618 Jungle: 14357619 Swamp: 14357620 Monument: 10387313 Ocean: 14357621 Shipwreck: 165745295 Slime: 987234911
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: RED_WALL_BANNER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: STONE_BRICKS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: STRIPPED_OAK_WOOD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: STRIPPED_JUNGLE_WOOD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: HORN_CORAL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: NETHER_BRICK_WALL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: DEAD_FIRE_CORAL_WALL_FAN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: WATER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LIGHT_GRAY_WALL_BANNER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PURPLE_WOOL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: JACK_O_LANTERN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BARREL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: TALL_SEAGRASS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LIGHT_GRAY_CONCRETE_POWDER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: CYAN_BED
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: DIAMOND_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: RED_NETHER_BRICK_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: CYAN_GLAZED_TERRACOTTA
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: END_STONE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LIME_WOOL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: RED_TERRACOTTA
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: SPRUCE_WOOD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: NETHER_WART
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: HAY_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: TUBE_CORAL_WALL_FAN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: END_STONE_BRICKS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PINK_GLAZED_TERRACOTTA
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BLACK_CONCRETE_POWDER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: INFESTED_STONE_BRICKS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: JUNGLE_SLAB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: RED_STAINED_GLASS_PANE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LIGHT_BLUE_BED
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: SANDSTONE_SLAB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: INFESTED_COBBLESTONE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LIME_SHULKER_BOX
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: SMOKER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: OAK_DOOR
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LILY_PAD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: DARK_OAK_DOOR
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: POPPY
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PODZOL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: CREEPER_HEAD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PINK_CARPET
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BEETROOTS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PURPLE_WALL_BANNER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: POTTED_CORNFLOWER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: DANDELION
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BUBBLE_CORAL_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: TALL_SEAGRASS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: DRAGON_EGG
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: COBBLESTONE_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: RED_NETHER_BRICK_WALL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BLUE_BANNER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: MAGMA_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: HONEY_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: STONE_BRICK_WALL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: COBWEB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BEEHIVE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: FIRE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: JUNGLE_PRESSURE_PLATE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: CHISELED_QUARTZ_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: NETHER_BRICKS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: MAGENTA_CONCRETE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: SPRUCE_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: ORANGE_CONCRETE_POWDER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: IRON_BARS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: RED_STAINED_GLASS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BUBBLE_CORAL_WALL_FAN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: SMITHING_TABLE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: STRUCTURE_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BROWN_TERRACOTTA
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: SMITHING_TABLE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: STONECUTTER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: STRIPPED_BIRCH_WOOD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PRISMARINE_BRICK_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: OAK_SIGN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: YELLOW_CARPET
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: GRASS_PATH
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BRICK_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: GREEN_CONCRETE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PRISMARINE_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: POLISHED_GRANITE_SLAB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LIGHT_GRAY_CONCRETE_POWDER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: DARK_OAK_SAPLING
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PURPLE_STAINED_GLASS_PANE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LARGE_FERN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PISTON_HEAD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: FERN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: MAGMA_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BEE_NEST
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BIRCH_LEAVES
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PINK_TULIP
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: NETHER_WART_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BROWN_MUSHROOM_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: DARK_OAK_WALL_SIGN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: SNOW_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BLUE_BANNER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LIGHT_BLUE_STAINED_GLASS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: SANDSTONE_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: GRINDSTONE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PRISMARINE_BRICK_SLAB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: DIORITE_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LIGHT_BLUE_BANNER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: SPRUCE_PRESSURE_PLATE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: RED_MUSHROOM_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: WHITE_CARPET
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: CYAN_SHULKER_BOX
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: CHORUS_FLOWER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: DAMAGED_ANVIL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BEDROCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BREWING_STAND
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: END_STONE_BRICKS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: YELLOW_WALL_BANNER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LIGHT_BLUE_STAINED_GLASS_PANE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: WHEAT
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PURPLE_GLAZED_TERRACOTTA
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: POTTED_AZURE_BLUET
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: CUT_SANDSTONE_SLAB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: COBBLESTONE_WALL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: BLACK_BED
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: WHITE_TULIP
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: PINK_CONCRETE_POWDER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: MUSHROOM_STEM
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: STRIPPED_SPRUCE_WOOD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: CAMPFIRE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: ENCHANTING_TABLE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: LAPIS_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: GRANITE_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: NETHER_BRICK_SLAB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: ANDESITE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: WITHER_ROSE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: YELLOW_CONCRETE_POWDER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: POWERED_RAIL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SPRUCE_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: END_PORTAL_FRAME
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: RED_MUSHROOM_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DANDELION
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: LIGHT_GRAY_SHULKER_BOX
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: JUNGLE_PRESSURE_PLATE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DEAD_TUBE_CORAL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: COMMAND_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: POTTED_CACTUS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: PURPUR_SLAB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: TUBE_CORAL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: NETHER_BRICK_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BIRCH_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: POLISHED_GRANITE_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: MOSSY_STONE_BRICKS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: OAK_WALL_SIGN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: STRIPPED_BIRCH_LOG
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: POTTED_RED_MUSHROOM
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BLACK_CONCRETE_POWDER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SMOOTH_SANDSTONE_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BLUE_STAINED_GLASS_PANE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SANDSTONE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BELL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: STRIPPED_SPRUCE_LOG
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DANDELION
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: GREEN_STAINED_GLASS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: LIGHT_BLUE_STAINED_GLASS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: PODZOL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SKELETON_SKULL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: ORANGE_TERRACOTTA
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BONE_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: END_STONE_BRICK_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DEAD_HORN_CORAL_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: POLISHED_GRANITE_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: PRISMARINE_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: CHORUS_FLOWER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BLACK_SHULKER_BOX
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: JACK_O_LANTERN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SKELETON_WALL_SKULL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: RED_SANDSTONE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: CAKE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: PUMPKIN_STEM
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DEAD_FIRE_CORAL_FAN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: LIGHT_GRAY_STAINED_GLASS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: HORN_CORAL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: WHITE_CONCRETE_POWDER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SPRUCE_FENCE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: STRIPPED_OAK_LOG
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DEAD_BUBBLE_CORAL_FAN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: RAIL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: PURPLE_SHULKER_BOX
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BEACON
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DEAD_FIRE_CORAL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: CONDUIT
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: CARROTS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: WHITE_BANNER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: CREEPER_HEAD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: HAY_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: NETHER_BRICK_SLAB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: COMPOSTER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: COBWEB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: WHITE_CONCRETE_POWDER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BEACON
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: KELP
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: END_ROD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: OAK_WOOD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SANDSTONE_SLAB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: GRANITE_WALL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BRICK_WALL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: TRIPWIRE_HOOK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SPONGE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: STRUCTURE_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: TUBE_CORAL_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: POTTED_CACTUS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: FLETCHING_TABLE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BLUE_BED
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BRAIN_CORAL_FAN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DARK_PRISMARINE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: END_GATEWAY
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: CUT_RED_SANDSTONE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: LILY_PAD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DIORITE_WALL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: RED_TULIP
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BELL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SPRUCE_LEAVES
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: OAK_TRAPDOOR
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BIRCH_TRAPDOOR
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: MAGENTA_BED
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: PURPLE_STAINED_GLASS_PANE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: NETHER_BRICK_FENCE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: PURPUR_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BAMBOO
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: WHEAT
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: STONE_BRICK_STAIRS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: LIME_STAINED_GLASS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: RED_NETHER_BRICK_WALL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BIRCH_TRAPDOOR
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: RED_SANDSTONE_WALL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: WITHER_ROSE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: NETHER_BRICK_SLAB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: NETHER_WART_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: LIGHT_GRAY_BANNER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: YELLOW_STAINED_GLASS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DEAD_FIRE_CORAL_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: ACACIA_PRESSURE_PLATE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: MAGENTA_CONCRETE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: RED_GLAZED_TERRACOTTA
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: ACACIA_WALL_SIGN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: CORNFLOWER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: MYCELIUM
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: MAGENTA_CARPET
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: CYAN_SHULKER_BOX
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: RED_SANDSTONE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: FIRE_CORAL_WALL_FAN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: MOSSY_STONE_BRICK_SLAB
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: STRIPPED_SPRUCE_LOG
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: RED_SANDSTONE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BROWN_CARPET
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: COARSE_DIRT
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: REDSTONE_LAMP
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: OAK_DOOR
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BIRCH_FENCE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: HORN_CORAL_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BLACK_WALL_BANNER
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: ANDESITE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BIRCH_PRESSURE_PLATE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: WET_SPONGE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: LIGHT_GRAY_CONCRETE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: CYAN_TERRACOTTA
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DARK_OAK_PLANKS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DARK_OAK_PRESSURE_PLATE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: IRON_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BROWN_SHULKER_BOX
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BROWN_GLAZED_TERRACOTTA
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: HORN_CORAL_WALL_FAN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: PUMPKIN_STEM
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DEAD_HORN_CORAL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: STRIPPED_ACACIA_LOG
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BLACK_WOOL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: WHITE_WOOL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: LILY_OF_THE_VALLEY
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DARK_OAK_SIGN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: RED_TULIP
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: CHORUS_PLANT
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SOUL_SAND
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: GREEN_CONCRETE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: LARGE_FERN
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: MAGENTA_STAINED_GLASS_PANE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BLUE_CONCRETE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: CAULDRON
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: MOSSY_STONE_BRICK_WALL
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: LIME_GLAZED_TERRACOTTA
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DRIED_KELP_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SPONGE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: POTTED_DANDELION
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BROWN_STAINED_GLASS
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: SNOW
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: DARK_OAK_FENCE_GATE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: ZOMBIE_WALL_HEAD
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: FLOWER_POT
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: POTTED_LILY_OF_THE_VALLEY
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: NETHER_WART_BLOCK
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BLUE_GLAZED_TERRACOTTA
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: BROWN_STAINED_GLASS_PANE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: PACKED_ICE
[10:46:20] [Server-Worker-3/FATAL]: Failed to schedule load callback for chunk [-7, 0]
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ReportedException: Exception generating new chunk
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkTaskQueueSorter.b(SourceFile:58) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ThreadedMailbox.e(SourceFile:83) [server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ThreadedMailbox.a(SourceFile:123) [server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ThreadedMailbox.run(SourceFile:91) [server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ReportedException: Exception generating new chunk
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerChunkMap.lambda$26(PlayerChunkMap.java:537) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at com.mojang.datafixers.util.Either$Left.map(Either.java:38) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerChunkMap.lambda$24(PlayerChunkMap.java:522) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ProtoChunk.setTileEntity(SourceFile:216) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.generator.CustomChunkGenerator.buildBase(CustomChunkGenerator.java:170) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkStatus.e(SourceFile:71) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkStatus$d.doWork(SourceFile:258) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkStatus.a(SourceFile:214) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerChunkMap.lambda$26(PlayerChunkMap.java:524) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at com.mojang.datafixers.util.Either$Left.map(Either.java:38) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerChunkMap.lambda$24(PlayerChunkMap.java:522) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        ... 12 more
[10:46:20] [Server thread/ERROR]: Encountered an unexpected exception
net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ReportedException: Exception generating new chunk
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.initWorld(MinecraftServer.java:491) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:441) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:274) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:784) [server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ProtoChunk.setTileEntity(SourceFile:216) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.generator.CustomChunkGenerator.buildBase(CustomChunkGenerator.java:170) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkStatus.e(SourceFile:71) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkStatus$d.doWork(SourceFile:258) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkStatus.a(SourceFile:214) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerChunkMap.lambda$26(PlayerChunkMap.java:524) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at com.mojang.datafixers.util.Either$Left.map(Either.java:38) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerChunkMap.lambda$24(PlayerChunkMap.java:522) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkTaskQueueSorter.b(SourceFile:58) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ThreadedMailbox.e(SourceFile:83) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ThreadedMailbox.a(SourceFile:123) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ThreadedMailbox.run(SourceFile:91) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
[10:46:20] [Server thread/ERROR]:       Cause of unexpected exception was
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ProtoChunk.setTileEntity(SourceFile:216) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.generator.CustomChunkGenerator.buildBase(CustomChunkGenerator.java:170) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkStatus.e(SourceFile:71) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkStatus$d.doWork(SourceFile:258) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkStatus.a(SourceFile:214) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerChunkMap.lambda$26(PlayerChunkMap.java:524) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at com.mojang.datafixers.util.Either$Left.map(Either.java:38) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerChunkMap.lambda$24(PlayerChunkMap.java:522) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ChunkTaskQueueSorter.b(SourceFile:58) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ThreadedMailbox.e(SourceFile:83) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ThreadedMailbox.a(SourceFile:123) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.ThreadedMailbox.run(SourceFile:91) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a03b1fd-5838285]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
```

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Something is null on CustomChunkGenerator.java line 170
You can check what is null by printing out 'object == null' and seeing what returns true